# How to safely add a lithiated reagent (R-Libenzene) to another flask using the NE-1002X syringe pump?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I would like to do a murahashi coupling (lithium coupling) between 1,4 dibromo benzene and 2,6-dinaphtalene-4-tertbutyl-iodobenzene.

I am trying to copy the exact procedure from this article:

Giannerini, M., Fañanás-Mastral, M. & Feringa, B. Direct catalytic cross-coupling of organolithium compounds. Nature Chem 5, 667–672 (2013). https://doi.org/10.1038/nchem.1678

Once 1,4 dilithium benzene obtained, I would like to add it to another flask where the catalyst and the other reagents are (as described in the original protocol).

I have never used a syringe pump before but we have the NE-1002X syringe pump. Gas tight syringes do not fit in it and thus require plastic syringes. Is there a possibility that the syringe may clog during the addition? Plastic syringes are not gas tight so any air could react with the lithiated specie and cause problem.

Hence has anyone ever done a similar reaction and could explain how to proceed safely?
Are there other types of syringe pumps which allow to use gas tight syringes to remain in an air free water free environment?

Thank you!

Comment: I have only ever done these kind of reactions by hand syringe or pressure-equalised dropping funnels, but rigid temperature control of the reaction mixture is key to getting a good yield. The dilithio benzene very easily decomposes with just a few degrees of warming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I presume you have access to a Schlenk line, an alternative approach may be a [cannula transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannula_transfer).

After the separate preparation of reagent(s) A in solution in flask A, a light additional pressure is used to transfer it to reagent(s) in flask B:

[image]

(with light edit, image credit to [schlenklinesurvivalguide.com](https://schlenklinesurvivalguide.com/cannula-transfer/))

The connection between the two flasks usually is established with a *transfer cannula*.  In contrast to the needles on the (injection) syringes, these double tip to pierce two septa, steal inox needles are available as wide bore/bigger inner diameter, can be baked out like your glass ware, and still are somewhat flexible for a *gentle* elbow.  There equally is one form where the two tips are joined with flexible tube between the two; Sigma for instance distributes them as *Chem-FLEX™ transfer line*, more useful for bigger quantities and larger distances to bridge:

[image]

(Sigma-Aldrich's [Chem-FLEX™ transfer line](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/z281751))

Except the transfer cannula, the setup can be immersed into a larger Dewar filled with dry ice and iPrOH, too:

[image]

(from Wikipedia article [Cannula transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannula_transfer)).

This approach will not provide reagent solution A at $\pu{-78 ^\circ{}C}$ to enter reagent solution B, is not suitable to add *this* slow (and enduring) as can the setup with a syringe pump.  With only a short tube connecting the two tips, the reagent however remains under inert conditions, *likely* much cooler than stored in a syringe mounted on a syringe pump, and relieves you from a search of a needle with fitting Luer lock to secure the joint.  If the technique is new to you, train the transfer a couple of times with the bleeding valve at the Schlenk line at room temperature with a bit of EtOAc, or THF before engaging the real reaction.

At a larger scale:

[image]

(image credit to Xu *et al.*)

---

An advanced version of this would be to set up *flow chemistry*, a topic for which for instance the group by [Steven Ley](http://www.leygroup.ch.cam.ac.uk/research/flow-synthesis) (Cambridge UK) is known for:

[image]

(image credit [Ley group](http://www.leygroup.ch.cam.ac.uk/research/continuous-flow-methodology/heterocycles-flow))

To design this, one needs to know the underlying kinetic data; then, chemical engineering steps in e.g., to estimate a useful *time of residence* in these *tube reactors*.  But once installed, up and running, the steady state of the continuous flow allows some operations (too) difficult/dangerous to apply with round bottom flasks, including lithiation reactions.

The author of schlenklinesurvivalguide.com equally compiled his experiences in a paper: Borys, A. M. An Illustrated Guide to Schlenk Line Techniques. *Organometallics* **2023**, *42*, 182–196. https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.organomet.2c00535.

Xu, H.-C.; Chowdhury, S.; Ellman, J. A. Asymmetric Synthesis of Amines Using *Tert*-Butanesulfinamide. *Nat. Protoc.* **2013**, *8*, 2271–2280. https://doi.org/10.1038/nprot.2013.134 (author's copy on [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258043177_Asymmetric_synthesis_of_amines_using_tert-butanesulfinamide)).

Brégent, T.; Ivanova, M. V.; Poisson, T.; Jubault, P.; Legros, J. Continuous‐Flow Divergent Lithiation of 2,3‐Dihalopyridines: Deprotolithiation versus Halogen Dance. *Chem. Eur. J.* **2022**, *28*, e202202286. https://doi.org/10.1002/chem.202202286 (open access).

Power, M.; Alcock, E.; McGlacken, G. P. Organolithium Bases in Flow Chemistry: A Review. *Org. Process Res. Dev.* **2020**, 24, 1814–1838. https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.oprd.0c00090 (author's copy [here](https://cora.ucc.ie/bitstreams/75496e15-54cd-476e-87d9-8cb2f6076009/download)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this extremely detailed and useful explanation. I am familiar with canula techniques but have never thought it could be suitable to add reagents at a controlled rate. I will try this! Thanks a lot! The details you provided will definitely help a lot.

Comment: @TheRedManJolanBonelli I moved a comment about *flow chemistry* as an advanced technique (compared to the transfer cannula) into the answer, because this can be appealing and worth the investment.  It depends ...

Comment: Since I do organic synthesis in academia at a research level in the material science field (no pure organic chemist), the cannula transfer method is more appropriate (I have everything I need and already am use to such protocols) I will definitely read up on the flow chemistry set ups as I am very unfamiliar with it. Thanks a lot for the extra information.